# Different server different output in same php version

Tags: php, postfix-operator, prefix-operator

I have two PHP server where i installed same php 5.6.8, but one server is windows and another is linux . When i write this code the output of code is different on different server.

```
$x=5;
echo $x."".++$x."".$x++;
```

Why does it give different answers on different server?

Comment: show me the difference

Comment: this is not even a valid syntax .

Comment: window output is 5 , 6 ,6 and linux oupt is 5,7,7

Comment: provide examples in the original post about what appears

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you considered issues with your Linux machine? I ran your code on my linux machine and I get 5, 6, 6.

Most Linux machines have gcc installed. Why don't you try putting this code in a file and compiling it with gcc. It will create an a.out file which is binary and you can run it. See if you have the same problem:

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
        int x = 5;
        printf("%d ", x);
        printf("%d ", ++x);
        printf("%d", x++);
}
```

Comment: So it means the process is completely base on compiler Or version

Comment: It honestly shouldn't make a difference. What is your processor?